# Mixed models question about the distribution

Tags: mixed-model

I got a normal mixed model with his general type being: **y**=**Xα**+**Zβ**+**e**.

I am confused about the distribution of **y**, **β**, **e** following. I know their elements following normal distribution but if I want to focus on their vectors, they are also following normal distributions or they following multivariate normal distribution?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but y does not have to be normally distributed. Only e does.

Comment: @PeterFlom I would start with the vector β. I have read that its following normal distribution with mean vector 0 and variance G (lets say), right? About y its not necessary
to following normal distribution? Is that what you telling me?

Comment: @PeterFlom I think I got it. Its the distribution of the response conditional on the random effects that is assumed to be normally distributed right?

Comment: Yes. That is, the error.